# Creating a Quantity Shortening Pipe in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I am currently creating a Pipe with the purpose of returning a substring of an input quantity. When a user enters a number, ex. 4000 - the custom pipe will prevent them from adding any additional numbers after the third 0. In other words, 400 is all it will accept. My Pipe TS currently looks like:

[.ts Pipe File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AawSi.png)

```
@Pipe({name: 'quantity'})
export class QuantityPipe implements PipeTransform{
  transform(value:string):string{
    if(value !== value.toString()){
      return;
    }
    return value.substring(0,3)
  }
}
```

My component.html file pipe implementation looks like this:

[.html Component Pipe Implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeE6U.png)

```
<input [ngModel]="food.quantity | quantity"  (ngModelChange)="food.quantity=$event" name="inputField" type="text">
```

When typing in a number over 3 characters, it does nothing. After some debugging, it appears the pipe is being used - however chrome console shows no change to value.

Anything stand out to you?

Comment: Oh I am not sure if you should use pipes for that. Cant you use input[type=number] with min/max? Or do a validator, let the user enter other values, but give him an error message.

Comment: It won't let me mark you as the selected answer, but I took your suggestion @CanK. as it was my original solution. A pipe won't effectively solve this issue.